# SAS: How to loop a macro over rows of data to change to missing

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

Can anyone help with this issue I'm having where the macro is only taking the final row value of the data?

I have some data that looks like this:

```
data data1 ;  
  infile datalines dsd dlm='|' truncover;  
  input id :$2. year_age_15 EDU_2000 EDU_2001 EDU_2002 ;  
datalines4;  
10|2000|3|4|5  
11|2000|5|5|6  
12|2001|1|2|3  
13|2002|5|5|6  
14|2001|2|2|2  
15|2000|3|3|4   
;;;;
```

However I need it to use the year variable to determine which data to keep, and then change all the values for the years after that value to missing, like so:

```
data data1 ;  
  infile datalines dsd dlm='|' truncover;  
  input id :$2. year_age_15 EDU_2000 EDU_2001 EDU_2002 ;  
datalines4;  
10|2000|3|.|.   
11|2000|5|.|.   
12|2001|1|2|.  
13|2002|5|5|6  
14|2001|2|2|.  
15|2000|3|.|.  
;;;;
```

I've been trying to get this macro to work, but it only works intermittently and works just for the final row of the data rather than looping through the rows.

```
%macro macro2 (output=, input=);  
data &output;  
set &input;  
%DO I = 1 %TO 6;  
%do; call symput('value2',trim(left(put(year_age_15,8.))));   
temp_col=&value2.;  
%let year_end=&value2.;  
%put YEAR END IS: &year_end.;  
%put EDU YEAR IS:  EDU_&year_end.;  
%do year = &year_end. %TO 2002;  
%put &year.;  
EDU_&year.=.;  
%end;  
%end;  
%end;  
run;  
%MEND macro2;  
%macro1(input=testset, output=output_testset);
```

In R it could be something simple like :
for(i in 1:6){.
*do this*
}

Any advice? I can't figure out which bit is going wrong, thanks!

Comment: Why would you try to use a macro for this type of problem?  Does the structure of the dataset change?  If so then describe how the dataset structure changes.

Comment: If you're an R->SAS user, then I suggest forgetting the macro language for a little while - it can be tempting to think of it as more like R, but it's really not the same thing.  Macro language is a pre-processor for the most part, it can create code for you but it's better to do things in the base language when possible.

Comment: FYI - you typically cannot use a macro variable created in a data step in the same data step. There are some ways around this limitation but it's usually means you're using the wrong approach for SAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Joe mentions, the year to match is part of a variable name, which is tremor inducing 'data in the metadata'

You can use the `VNAME` to retrieve the variable name of an index accessed array element.  Use that feature to compare to expected variable name whilst looping over a *variable array* based on variables named `EDU*`.

Example:

```
data have ;  
  infile datalines dsd dlm='|' truncover;  
  input id :$2. year_age_15 EDU_2000 EDU_2001 EDU_2002 ;  
datalines4;  
10|2000|3|4|5  
11|2000|5|5|6  
12|2001|1|2|3  
13|2002|5|5|6  
14|2001|2|2|2  
15|2000|3|3|4   
;;;;

data want;
  set have;
  array edus edu_:;

  * find index of element corresponding to variable name having year;
  do _n_ = 1 to dim(edus) until (upcase(vname(edus(_n_))) = cats('EDU_',year_age_15));
  end;

  * fill in elements at indices post the found one with missing values;
  do _n_ = _n_+1 to dim(edus);
    call missing(edus(_n_));
  end;  
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!  This did the trick and works well when I need to find for different years too (i.e. age 16) :D

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an array and index it by years rather than default 1:n
2. Loop through your array starting at year+1 and set to missing

   ```
   data want;
    set data1;
    array educ(2000:2002) edu_2000-edu_2002;
    if (year_age_15 +1) <= hbound(educ) then do i= (year_age_15 +1) to hbound(educ);
       call missing(educ(i));
    end;
    run;
   ```

Comment: IF should test that `year_age_15 >= LBOUND(educ)-1`.  The test for beyond HBOUND() will be built into the DO loop.  Or perhaps change the START point of the DO loop to `max(lbound(educ),year_age_15+1)`

Comment: I was testing if it's past the end of the loop before it starts, such as in the last record. It works as expected, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Reeza The issue is if year_age_15 is say 1995 then it fails. Your test isn't really needed since `do x = 90 to 1` is perfectly legal and will immediately terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think the issue here is your data is at the wrong level.  You certainly can do what Reeza suggests, and I think it's probably reasonable to do so, but the reason why this is a bit complicated is that you have data in your variable name.  That's not a best practice - your variable name should be "education" and your data should have a row for each year.  Then this would be a simple WHERE statement!

Here's a simple `PROC TRANSPOSE` that turns it to the right structure, and then if you really need it the other way, a second one will turn it back.  The `where` statement can be in the `proc transpose` or could be used somewhere else.

```
proc transpose data=data1 out=data_t (where=(year_Age_15 ge input(scan(_NAME_,2,'_'),4.)));
  by id year_Age_15;
  var edu_:;
run;

proc transpose data=data_t out=want;
  by id year_age_15;
  id _name_;
  var col1;
run;
```